# Why is the BASE file generated by TortoiseGit in merge conflict resolution 0 bytes?

Tags: git, git-merge, tortoisegit, merge-conflict-resolution

I am finding the built-in TortoiseGitMerge tool very underpowered at dealing with even slightly complex changes, so am looking for an external tool that might do a better job.

I am trialling WinMerge, however in the three-pane merge, the left pane is empty and titled 'base'. In the repository, TortoiseGit has created for `file.cs`

```
file.cs.BASE.cs
file.cs.LOCAL.cs
file.cs.REMOTE.cs
```

The local and remote files are populated, but the base file is 0 bytes, when the documentation suggests this is should contain the unmodified file. What am I doing wrong?

The automatically generated WinMerge call is

```
C:\Program Files\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe /e /ub /fr /wl /wm /dl %bname /dm %tname /dr %yname  %base %theirs %mine /o %merged /ar
```

While I haven't found documentation on the macro names, I presume `%base` is passing the name file.cs.BASE.cs, which is empty, and showing that file in the left window.

**Update:** Having found the [documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html) it doesn't shed any further light on why the *.BASE.cs file is empty, and the suggestion is that the command line is correct.

Comment: Isn't it possible that `file.cs` doesn't exist yet at common ancestor (base) revision?

Comment: This is what I'm working with right now. KDiff3 seems to be able to choose any common base (I choose local), while having all the other features I want. I don't know why it would ever make sense to do a baseless merge. In my codebase a file from the branch was brought to the master, now I'm trying to bring a later master to the latest branch. To me it is clear what needs to be compared.

Comment: Does it look like this? Then the base revision should indeed be clear (R2). https://imgur.com/hPySXXp

Comment: I think what's happened is I've created a file in a branch, another dev has copied it to the master and made changes. So as far as git knows, it's two files, same names, no common origin, even though in reality they are common. The merge tools see this as two massive changes from nothing to file content, with no idea how to gracefully merge them. What Kdiff3 has at least is the ability to choose the base file.

..so no, it doesn't look like that.

Comment: I think you could solve this be creating a separate branch from the revision where another dev commited your file, make your changes on this branch and then merge with upstream. Thus the base should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

The BASE file is zero bytes when there is no common file origin to draw from in the merge. This is not covered in the [TortoiseGit documentation](https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-conflicts.html), however does appear with the phrase 'if available' in the underlying [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool).

This can happen if a file is copied outside of a merge operation between branches that are later merged.

There is no graceful handling of the case where there is no base file, and many merge tools do not work well in this case. Kdiff3 does at least allow manually setting the base file to one or other files, allowing the merge to proceed.